# onClientClick in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm new kinda to asp.net.I'm little bit confused on `onClientClick` in below statement. Can any one please clarify me what it is.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Image" AlternateText="Transfer All Components" CommandName="TransferAllComponents" ToolTip="Transfer All Components"                         OnClientClick="ShowTransferAllComponents('TransferAllComponents'); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

onClientClick refers to a javascript method on the page

[Documentation Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This compares to the onClick event that causes a postback and runs server side code

Answer (score 0):

OnClientClick is used to run javascript code on the client (your web browser). The Click event will make a full postback to run code on the web server hosting the website.

If used in conjunction with an ASP.NET `OnClick` event (on the server), the OnClientClick will be executed first. If the javascript executed by the OnClientClick returns true, then the OnClick will be executed. If it returns false, the OnClick event won't be executed.

Comment: "ShowTransferAllComponents('TransferAllComponents'); return false;" can u please tell me what it is.I mean how it is possible to call(in brackets)

Comment: ShowTransferAllComponents is a javascript function that is being invoked as a result of the 'Click' event being fired from the web page.

Comment: Thanks Ciaran Gallagher

Answer (score 0):

In this case `OnClientClick` is pointing to a function **ShowTransferAllComponents** which accepts a string as parameter..

```
function ShowTransferAllComponents(abc)
{
    alert(abc);
}
```

Here **abc** stores the string you have passed..`return false` is used to prevent the server side event not to fire..

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp) for extra reading..

Comment: Thanks jameem. Really help full.

Comment: Please feel free to mark as answer by clicking on the TICK mark on the left of the answer if the answer is helpful,Regards